# Is there any way for reading two or more files in one Java8-stream?

Tags: java, file-io, java-8, java-stream

I like new Java8 StreamAPI and want use it not only for one file. 
As usually, I use this code:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("/somepathtofile"));
```

But how read two file in one stream if it possibly?

Comment: I dont see the point in it. Both files will have different number of lines. One might get over when you read the other. What is your use case?

Comment: @jatin , I have log files wich rotate every day. I need parse all logs for last 24 hours. I want get two logfiles(for today and yestreday) put them in one stream and apply "filter"-function.

Comment: You mean a stream from both files for the same timestamp?

Comment: yes, but for the same time range. log entries for last 24 hours may be in today logfile(2015-04-17 12:09) and yestreday log(2015-04-16 23:55)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without any extra helper functions or outside libraries, the easiest is:

```
Stream<String> lines1 = Files.lines(Paths.get("/somepathtofile"));
Stream<String> lines2 = Files.lines(Paths.get("/somepathtoanotherfile"));

Stream.concat(lines1, lines)
    .filter(...)
    .forEach(...);
```

If `Files.lines` hadn't been declared to throw a checked exception, you'd be able to do

```
Stream.of("/file1", "/file2")
     .map(Paths::get)
     .flatMap(Files::lines)....
```

But, alas, we can't do that.  There are several workarounds.  One is to make your own version of `Files.lines` that calls the standard one, catches `IOException` and rethrows as an `UncheckedIOException`.  Another approach is a more general way to make functions out of methods that throw checked exceptions.  It would look something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T,R> extends Function<T,R> {

    @Override
    public default R apply(T t) {
        try {
            return throwingApply(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static<T,R> Function<T,R> wrap(ThrowingFunction<T,R> f) {
        return f;
    }

    R throwingApply(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

and then

```
Stream.of("/somefile", "/someotherfile", "/yetanotherfile")
        .map(Paths::get)
        .flatMap(ThrowingFunction.wrap(Files::lines))
        .....
```

There are several libraries out there that went through the trouble of writing something like the above out for every functional interface.

Comment: oh, thanks. I try found something look like this in streamAPI source but failed

Comment: You are great, but can tell me is this way better then simple public static Stream<String> ownlines(Path path)  {
        try {
            return Files.lines(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: @mechanikos `return null` is bad.  Instead do `try {return Files.lines(p);} catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e);}`.

Comment: It's not better or worse.  It's different.  If you find yourself running into similar issues frequently with checked exceptions, you probably should use a general purpose solution that you can apply everywhere.  If it's just this one time, perhaps the modest solution is more appropriate.  Whatever you feel leaves your code easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
Files.list(Paths.get("path"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .flatMap(s -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(s);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [cyclops-streams](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams) (a library we have created) you can write

```
  SequenceM.of("/somepathtofile1","/somepathtofile2")
             .flatMapFile(File::new)
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[Javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-sequence-api/6.0.1/com/aol/cyclops/sequence/SequenceM.html) SequenceM extends java.util.stream.Stream (and also org.jooq.lambda.Seq) to add a lot of additional convenience methods.